# how to make a yocto build install dev files

Tags: yocto, recipe, yocto-recipe

I'm trying to get the files that are in the FILES_${PN}-dev and FILES_${PN}-lib part of this recipe to install: [PCSC-lite](http://cgit.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded/tree/meta-oe/recipes-support/pcsc-lite/pcsc-lite_1.9.0.bb?h=hardknott)

However, when adding the recipe i see that the files in FILES_${PN} are installed, but not the rest. Is there a way i can make the generated image contain the files in the dev and lib parts of this recipe? I'm converting from an old rocko based image, and when i add it there, the files are in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have somewhere in your image file `IMAGE_INSTALL += pcsc-lite` which installs `FILES_${PN}` to your target.

In order to install the rest you want, you should add `pcsc-lite-dev` and `pcsc-lite-lib` to your `IMAGE_INSTALL` variable.